# Is there an R function to split the sentence

Tags: r

I have couple of unstructured sentences like below. Description below is column name

```
Description

Automatic lever for a machine
Vaccum chamber with additional spare
Glove box for R&D
The Mini Guage 5 sets
Vacuum chamber only
Automatic lever only
```

I want to split this sentence from Col1 to Col5 and count there occurrence like below

```
Col1             Col2            Col3               Col4               
Automatic_lever lever_for        for_a               a_machine  
Vaccum_chamber  chamber_with     with_additional    additional_spare     
Glove_box       box_for          for_R&D            R&D 
The_Mini        Mini_Guage       Guage_5             5_sets 
Vacuum_chamber  chamber_only     only       
Automatic_lever lever_only       only
```

Also from above columns, can i have the occurence of these words. Like, Vaccum_chamber and Automatic_lever are repeated twice here. Similarly, the occurence of other words?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` option

```
df %>%
    rowid_to_column("row") %>%
    mutate(words = map(str_split(Description, " "), function(x) {
        if (length(x) %% 2 == 0) words <- c(words, "")
        idx <- 1:(length(words) - 1)
        map_chr(idx, function(i) paste0(x[i:(i + 1)], collapse = "_"))
    })) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    group_by(row) %>%
    mutate(
        words = str_replace(words, "_NA", ""),
        col = paste0("Col", 1:n())) %>%
    filter(words != "NA") %>%
    spread(col, words, fill = "")
## A tibble: 6 x 6
## Groups:   row [6]
#    row Description                Col1        Col2       Col3       Col4
#  <int> <fct>                      <chr>       <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
#1     1 Automatic lever for a mac… Automatic_… lever_for  for_a      a_machine
#2     2 Vaccum chamber with addit… Vaccum_cha… chamber_w… with_addi… additional…
#3     3 Glove box for R&D          Glove_box   box_for    for_R&D    R&D
#4     4 The Mini Guage 5 sets      The_Mini    Mini_Guage Guage_5    5_sets
#5     5 Vacuum chamber only        Vacuum_cha… chamber_o… only       ""
#6     6 Automatic lever only       Automatic_… lever_only only       ""
```

Explanation: We split the sentences in `Description` on a single whitespace `" "`, then concatenate every two words together with a sliding window approach, making sure that there are always an odd odd number of words per `sentence`; the rest is just a long-to-wide transformation.

Not pretty but it reproduces your expected output; instead of the manual sliding window approach you could also you `zoo::rollapply`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Description
'Automatic lever for a machine'
'Vaccum chamber with additional spare'
'Glove box for R&D'
'The Mini Guage 5 sets'
'Vacuum chamber only'
'Automatic lever only'", header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks I got. But incode col = paste0("Col1", 1:n())), the column names are like COl1, COL11, COL12,.........COL2..... I mean to say it is not sorted, Can we change this code so that the columns are sorted like COL1, COL2, COL3 and so on

Comment: @Dev Try replacing `paste0("Col", 1:n())` with `sprintf("Col%02i", 1:n())`; this assumes that you have at most 99 columns. If you have >99 columns, change to `"Col%03i"` and so on.

Comment: PS. A final word of advice. If I were you, I'd keep my data in the long (=tidy) instead of wide format; tidy (long) data is often easier to process in downstream analyses. It is certainly more in-line with the data processing paradigm of the `tidyverse`.

Comment: @Mauritus. Perfect thanks, Can you explain what is the logic here. I did not get?

Comment: @Dev `sprintf` makes use of the C library function `sprintf` to format output. In this case the critical part is `sprinf("%02i", x)` which means, format `x` as an integer (`"i"`), with two digits (`"2"`), and leading zeros (`"0"`). The `%` is the character that denotes the start of a `sprintf` flag.